# Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings, log back-classic and log4j

Tags: java, maven, dependency-properties, pom.xml, apache-storm

getting below error when i try to run unit test in my java project:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. 
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.8/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/me/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.6/logback-classic-1.0.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] 
SLF4J: See slf4j.org/… for an explanation.
```

My pom.xml does have these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version> 
        </dependency>
```

My mvn dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] +- storm:storm:jar:0.9.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- storm:storm-console-logging:jar:0.9.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- storm:storm-core:jar:0.9.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- storm:libthrift7:jar:0.7.0-2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- clj-time:clj-time:jar:0.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.curator:curator-framework:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.curator:curator-client:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.3.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- backtype:jzmq:jar:2.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- compojure:compojure:jar:1.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.clojure:core.incubator:jar:0.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.clojure:tools.macro:jar:0.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- clout:clout:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ring:ring-core:jar:1.1.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- hiccup:hiccup:jar:0.3.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- ring:ring-devel:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- clj-stacktrace:clj-stacktrace:jar:0.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- ring:ring-jetty-adapter:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ring:ring-servlet:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clojure:tools.logging:jar:0.2.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clojure:math.numeric-tower:jar:0.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- storm:carbonite:jar:1.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.17:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- storm:tools.cli:jar:0.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.disruptor:disruptor:jar:2.10.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- storm:jgrapht:jar:0.8.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  \- storm:storm-netty:jar:0.9.0.1:provided
[INFO] |     \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.3.Final:provided
[INFO] +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.6.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:test
[INFO] +- org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:jar:2.0M8:test
[INFO] |  \- org.easytesting:fest-util:jar:1.2.3:test
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile
```

Edit 1:
After removing log4j dependency tree

```
 +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] +- storm:storm:jar:0.9.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- storm:storm-console-logging:jar:0.9.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- storm:storm-core:jar:0.9.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clojure:clojure:jar:1.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- storm:libthrift7:jar:0.7.0-2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- clj-time:clj-time:jar:0.4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.curator:curator-framework:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.curator:curator-client:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.3.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- backtype:jzmq:jar:2.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- compojure:compojure:jar:1.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.clojure:core.incubator:jar:0.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.clojure:tools.macro:jar:0.1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- clout:clout:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ring:ring-core:jar:1.1.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- hiccup:hiccup:jar:0.3.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- ring:ring-devel:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- clj-stacktrace:clj-stacktrace:jar:0.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- ring:ring-jetty-adapter:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ring:ring-servlet:jar:0.3.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clojure:tools.logging:jar:0.2.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clojure:math.numeric-tower:jar:0.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- storm:carbonite:jar:1.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.17:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- storm:tools.cli:jar:0.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.googlecode.disruptor:disruptor:jar:2.10.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- storm:jgrapht:jar:0.8.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.6:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:provided
[INFO] |  \- storm:storm-netty:jar:0.9.0.1:provided
[INFO] |     \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.3.Final:provided
[INFO] +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.11.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.6.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:test
[INFO] +- org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:jar:2.0M8:test
[INFO] |  \- org.easytesting:fest-util:jar:1.2.3:test
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile
```

And pom.xml

```
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

  <repositories> 
      <repository> 
        <id>clojars.org</id> 
        <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url> 
      </repository> 
    </repositories> 

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Storm library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RabbitMQ Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mongodb java driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <!-- Unit Testing Tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0M8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.testng</groupId> <artifactId>testng</artifactId> 
            <version>6.8</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->

        <!-- Google JSON serialization -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Encoder -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

        <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>stage</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>stage</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <delete file="src/main/resources/application.properties" />
                                <copy file="profiles/application.${build.profile.id}.properties"
                                    tofile="src/main/resources/application.properties" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.madisonlogic.conscriptor.topology.ConscriptorTopology</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Used to Correct slf4j errors with log4j -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <bannedDependencies>
                                    <searchTransitive>true</searchTransitive>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>commons-logging</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.slf4j:1.5*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.slf4j:1.6*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.springframework:2.*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org.springframework:3.0.*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </bannedDependencies>
                            </rules>
                            <fail>true</fail>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Edit 2 Updated pom.xml

```
<!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                  <version>1.5.8</version>
              </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like `storm:storm:jar:0.9.0.1` provides you `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.6`, which is causing the conflict. With slf4j you can only use one logger implementation. In your case log4j OR logback.

Comment: ok so i need to bind slf4j with logback then intend of log4j any ideas, how to do that?

Comment: To remove the log4j binding, remove the `org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6` dependency. The `org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6` if for Jakarta Commons Logging; maybe you don't need that too.

Comment: I removed all dependancies in pom.xml relating to log4j still getting the same error when i debug in eclipse

Comment: Did you post your complete dependency:tree ? Another thing you should look is your classpath. Looks like you have other jar packages in your classpath (and these will not show up in the dependency:tree)

Comment: i just posted the dependency tree again with pom.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60850/discussion-between-ericbn-and-jaminator).

Comment: Did my answer help you?  Adding the exclusion is all you need.  If you continue to have issues (more conflicts), you will need to make a decision on which JARs need to stay and add the exclusions for the ones that are causing the issue.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb i am trying you answer right now, 1 min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It was in /.classpath. I compared the class path file with a working project and deleted any additional references. And it worked.

The bad class path had alot of jar specific references like below

```
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO...
```

Below is a diff b/t bad class path file on left, and correct class path file on right.
[image]

I have no idea on how those class path entry got in.